# Select default option in a dropdown, save the value in the value attribute of the dropdown. Angular.js. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen infinity of post to try to choose by default an option in a dropdown. But I have not been able to achieve it. I have an array of some countries.

```
$scope.regions = 
 [
      {
        name: "COLOMBIA",
        code: 5
      },
      {
        name: "ARGENTINA",
        code: 6
      },
      {
        name: "BRAZIL",
        code: 7
      }
  ];
```

I have this variable:

```
$scope.selectThisId={
    "id":6,
    "animal":'dog',
    "variable":'xxx32'
 };
```

I need the dropdown value to be equal to the id attribute of the

```
$scope.region=$scope.selectThisId.id;
```

variable.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nmc8iLz6BIFac0Swfth8?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/zhye91pDUEMgaZnXZGWE?p=preview

You basically create a default region by doing

```
$scope.select = $scope.selectThisId.id;
$scope.regionSelected = {};
```

then create a `select` tag with `ng-options`, binding it to the model, and calling `ng-init` on the model.

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in regions track by item.code" 
        ng-model="regionSelected" ng-init="regionSelected.code = select">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve my problem. I need to select the id I have in another variable other than the json that has the array. I recreated my problem in your example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/nmc8iLz6BIFac0Swfth8?p=preview

Comment: it not works for me...http://plnkr.co/edit/tnXZlzXI0r3g8JrdcWQq?p=preview I update thte link. Why can not you simply put $scope.select = $scope.selectThisId.id; ??

Comment: You cannot set `ng-model` to be an id. The model should have both the `name` and `code`

Comment: thanks you. you are very friendly. What I can do in my case, I strictly need to select the id that is in another variable.

Comment: It did not help me. I did what you put and it did not work for me. I told you.
plnkr.co/edit/tnXZlzXI0r3g8JrdcWQq?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't work because you cannot bind the `select` tag to a model that is just a number (an `id` in your case). You have to make your `ng-model` object an object that has both the name and code of the region to show it properly.\

Comment: respectfully. That answers to if your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to your controller to get the default region (don't forget to add `$filter` after `$scope`):

```
$scope.defaultValue = $filter('filter')($scope.regions, {code: $scope.selectThisId.id}, true)[0];
```

and then add this to your select in your view

```
ng-init="select = defaultValue"
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RRUQcm0MMgYhuFRKkdYN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1242/)

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.regions = 
 [
      {
        name: "COLOMBIA",
        code: 5
      },
      {
        name: "ARGENTINA",
        code: 6
      },
      {
        name: "BRAZIL",
        code: 7
      }
  ];
  
  $scope.selectThisId={
    "id":6,
    "animal":'dog',
    "variable":'xxx32'
 };
 
 $scope.region=$scope.selectThisId.id;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in regions"
            ng-model="region"></select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```